# How could I change the Arabic font for a certain font while keeping the English font the same?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I want to use the Amiri font (which is good looking for Arabic words)
but the English in it is not good looking, I want to replace it with Lato.

So I want one font to show Arabic words in Amiri, and English fonts in Lato, How could I do this?

Comment: I think this can be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838075/stylize-text-to-use-different-fonts-for-different-languages

Comment: @Bayrem No, This is different. I don't want to load two fonts. When the font designer designed the font, he/she could have used any font for English, I want to change that and have just one font. I want to edit the font itself, not a work around.  -Thanks for your reference